# program using up all memory from listview sql table, how to populate with only the relevant data?

Tags: c#, listview

i think i have a listview that's using all my memory.  let me explain what i'm doing

i have a device that i take messages from, i timestamp them, and i add them to a sqldatabase

```
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Messages (Time, Message) Values ('" + DateTime.Now + "', '"+sqlMessage+"')", myConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            UpdateTable();
```

here's how i update my listview:

```
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            adapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Messages";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);


            lvwMessages.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            myConnection.Close();
```

when i leave this running for a while, my program usually runs out of memory. i'm assuming it's the listview getting too many messages loading from the database.  but let's say i have 15 lines of messages i need on the screen displayed.  how do i only load the 15 that i need, then pop the ones off that don't need to be displayed out of memory, and load the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to only select the 15 most recent:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 15 * FROM Messages ORDER BY Time Desc";
```

`TOP 15` means to select only the first 15 rows returned, and the `ORDER BY` makes sure they're sorted by `Time` (the `DESC` makes them sort from highest (most recent) to lowest, petting the most recent at the beginning).

(You didn't mention what DBMS, so I posted one that works in SQL Server. You should include the appropriate database engine tag in future questions here, as SQL syntax and functionality can vary between them.)

Comment: is there some sort of method that listview provides that has this built in instead of hitting up the server for a few lines of code? i would imagine this wouldn't perform as well if i have to hit the database when i start to scroll

Comment: That's not what you asked here. :-) Your specific question was "how do i only load the 15 that i need, then pop the ones off that don't need to be displayed out of memory, and load the new ones", which is what I answered. If you have a new, different question, you should post a new question and ask it. You can link this one from there for some context.