# how to load displayed sql data into wpf scrollable list view? large collection (20k+) without running into memory problems?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

i have a large collection in a sql database. when i use `DataSet`, i'm assuming i'm pulling all (and when I say all, i mean 20000+) database entries at once to populate a scrollable WPF list view.  when i pull that much data, and more data is added, i'm running out of memory.

i asked a similar question here:[program using up all memory from listview sql table, how to populate with only the relevant data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752686/program-using-up-all-memory-from-listview-sql-table-how-to-populate-with-only-t) and i need to use it with a list view.

how do i only pull the data i need when the user scrolls? would `DataRead` work here?  i've seen tutorials on DataRead, but they're usually button based, and i need to dynamically read the data based on which direction the user scrolls in the list view.

is there a way to make it update based on, say 30, values, if the user sees 15 of them, then the lag between the server query and returned value wouldn't cause the list view to have any problems as the user scrolls up or down?

Comment: WPF has built-in UI virtualization, assuming you didn't break it, I wouldn't worry too much about UI. You're looking for Data Virtualization, which is a different concept and has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: okay.  is there any examples of this anywhere? I'm hard pressed to think I'm the only one who's every asked this question before, or wanted to do this with a listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the next link [Data virtualization in codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

Comment: I saw this article and the other http://www.zagstudio.com/blogfiles/52/DataVirtualization.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> i'm assuming i'm pulling all (and when I say all, i mean 20000+) database entries at once to populate a scrollable WPF list view

Why? Can you imagine anyone analyzing 20000+ elements **at once**? Do you expect your users to look at 20000+ elements **at once**? You should have a very good reason to pull entire data set at once. *"To display for users"* is rarely such reason.

Those kind of problems are usually dealt with in either of two ways:

1. [**Pagination**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784726/how-can-i-paginate-a-wpf-datagrid). To improve user experience you can always fetch couple extra pages upfront, so that transitioning between pages is seamless.
2. [**Virtualization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Supporting). Most WPF controls have this feature built in ([can be easily enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Unless you changed your `ListView` `ItemContainer` (from `VirtualizingStackPanel` to something else) or manually disabled virtualization, it should work fine.

On the SQL side, you want to have queries with *limit* and *offset* to decide at runtime which part of data set should be fetched.

Comment: Virtualizaton of the displayed data is not the issue. The OP is struggling with a very large ObservableCollection that causes a memory problem. The viewport is virtualized using DataGrid or one of the other VirtualizingStackPanel-based controls. However, when the backing data model gets too large, then there are problems. It really has nothing to do with trying to *see* the data - it is just that the data exist in the ObservableCollection. Having the same problem myself.