# System.OutOfMemoryException while load data from datatable which have more than 2million rows to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to assign DataTable as an itemsource of dataGrid1 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dtselect.DefaultView but it give System.OutOfMemoryException

I have one dataset which has multiple DataTable. I randomly create a button on that button click I want to show data from DataTable to dataGrid1 but the problem here is DataTable has more than 2 million rows and when I am clicking on a button it will take more than 2gb ram and give me System.OutOfMemoryException.

```
Button = sender as Button;
                    string content = button.Content.ToString();
                    foreach (DataTable table in dsr.Tables)
                    {
                        if (table.TableName == content)
                        {
                            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                            dtselect = table;
                        }
                    }
```

I expect the output of less memory use and display result instead of System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to load so much data into a DataTable?

Comment: Obviously, you can't display 2M rows in a UI. What would be the point anyways? You think a person can process 2M rows? Nope. Re-think what you're doing.

Comment: I want to display data on datagrid to apply filters s

Comment: [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810507/how-to-load-displayed-sql-data-into-wpf-scrollable-list-view-large-collection/21816679)

Comment: Your fundamental architecture of reading a huge dataset at a time is a mistake. Don't read a whole database into memory. Don't display data and then apply filters. Apply the filter, read the data and display. If reasonable user behaviour will return more than 200 rows then page the data using linq skip and take.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load displayed sql data into wpf scrollable list view? large collection (20k+) without running into memory problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810507/how-to-load-displayed-sql-data-into-wpf-scrollable-list-view-large-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="3" Stretch="Fill">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Row="3" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" BorderThickness="0" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Height="600" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   Background="#b5d2fc"  ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Day"  Binding="{Binding Day}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Lat" Binding="{Binding Lat}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Long" Binding="{Binding Long}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="400" Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Accuracy" Binding="{Binding Accuracy}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                </Viewbox>
```

I simply add Viewbox and my code works fine if I load more than two files which have huge data then also it consume less memory